# What is the meaning of bold part in the following sentence

Tags: meaning

Long before ISI became **a dreaded acronym courtesy the notorious** Inter-Services Intelligence of Pakistan, it was associated with a (failed) economic strategy practiced by India and several other developing countries: Import Substitution
Industrialisation.

Comment: IMHO, that's a mistake. it should read: *Long before ISI became a dreaded acronym courtesy **of** the notorious Inter-Services Intelligence of Pakistan...*

Answer (score 1):

"Notorious" modifies "[the] Inter-Services Intelligence." "Courtesy the ...Inter-Services Intelligence of Pakistan" is a phrase modifying "ISI became a dreaded acronym."

Long before ISI became a dreaded acronym--**courtesy of** the notorious Inter-Services Intelligence of Pakistan--it was associated with a (failed) economic strategy practiced by India and several other developing countries: Import Substitution Industrialisation.

ISI became a dreaded acronym; that is, people dreaded to hear the term ISI, owing to the fact that the Inter-Services Intelligence (the institution for which *ISI* stands) is notorious in Pakistan (notorious = well known for bad reasons). But ISI had already been dreaded for a long time because it stands for a failed economic strategy--*Import Substitution Industrialisation.*

*Courtesy* here might better be *courtesy of*, meaning "thanks to," an ironic usage, since the phrase purports to thank the ones responsible for something bad--as if they had done it out of courtesy or consideration for others.

Answer (score -1):

... ill-famed letter combination, due to the well-known...

Comment: This isn't correct: **dreaded** doesn't mean *ill-famed*, it means *deeply feared* (which is quite different), and **notorious** means much more than just *well-known*, it means *ill-famed*!

Comment: **Ominous** would be a better choice to replace ill-famed (_deeply feared letters_ would sound strange), however the question wasn't about exact meanings of separate _words_, it was more important to make it clearer to which parts of the sentence those words refer.

Comment: Um, no... Firstly, *ominous* is to *dreaded* as *worrying* is to *terrifying*. Secondly, the exact meanings **are** important, as otherwise you convey the wrong impression. See [Vichara's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/474840/167396) as a good demonstration of a *detailed* answer that *explains* why it's correct. :-)